# Passing a copy of a class is altering the original copy

Tags: c#, class

I have some code that downloads data into a class for storage and then creates a copy of that class to pass into a method that alters the data. Somehow my original class is also being altered and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
Calculations calc = new Calculations(Symbol, Market);
calc.stockData = loadData(Symbol, Market);
for (int j = calc.stockData.Count - 8; j >= 0; j--)
                    {
                        highPrice = 0;

                        // 0 newest
                        // as you go higher in the index, it is older
                        for (int k = j + 1; k < j + 8; k++)
                        {
                            kIndex = k;
                            jIndex = j;
                            decimal highRiskCurrentHigh = Calculations.calculateReturnPercentageStatic(calc.stockData.ElementAtOrDefault(k).Close,
                                calc.stockData.ElementAtOrDefault(j).High);

                            if (highRiskCurrentHigh > highPrice)
                            {
                                highPrice = highRiskCurrentHigh;
                                highIndex = k;
                            }
                        }

                        Test test = new Test();
                        test.returnPct = highPrice;
                        test.date = calc.stockData.ElementAtOrDefault(highIndex).Date;
                        test.symbolClass = symbolsList.ElementAtOrDefault(i);
                        Calculations copy = calc;
                        test.ratingClass = performCalculations(test.symbolClass, copy, test.date); // passing a copy into the method for altering
                        stuffList.Add(test); // inserted a breakpoint here and the original class (calc) has been altered
                    }
```

Comment: Have you read about references to objects before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's walk through your code so you understand what is happening here. (What you are telling your code to do is written in the comments.)

```
// 1. create a new instance of the object 'Calculations' on the heap
// 2. return the memory address of that instance and assign it to variable 'calc'
Calculations calc = new Calculations(Symbol, Market);

// 3. Create a variable called 'copy' that points to 'Calculations' type objects
// 4. Assign the value of 'calc' (which is a reference to the heap object) to 'copy'
Calculations copy = calc;
```

Simply put, in your code `calc` and `copy` are pointing to the same object in memory. That is why changes to `copy` are affecting `calc`. What you need to do is clone your object so that you have a new object that is equal in value but separate in memory.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this for me! I will mark this as the answer soon

Comment: @user3610374 You're welcome! You may want to read this article that is helpful for explaining how variables and reference/value types work in C# http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html and  http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/memory.html.

Answer (score 5):

This code does not create a copy:

```
Calculations copy = calc;
```

In C# objects all exist on the heap and are manipulated through references, compare to C++ where you can create objects on the stack and assignment is equal to a copy operation.

Instead, implement `IClonable` and provide your own copy operation.

Comment: Microsoft no longer recommends using the ICloneable interface. See the "[Notes to Implmenters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable(v=vs.110).aspx)" section of the documentation. *"[The ICloneable interface] does not specify whether the cloning operation performs a deep copy, a shallow copy, or something in between. [...] Because callers of Clone cannot depend on the method performing a predictable cloning operation, we recommend that ICloneable not be implemented in public APIs."*

Answer (score 3):

```
Calculations copy = calc;
```

is not creating a copy of your original data it is a reference to the same data. 
You need to clone this data.

More info on how to clone can be found here :

[Deep cloning objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects)

Comment: Thanks for the great link which helped me fix my problem